# How could I change the label size of fviz_cos2 plot in R?

Tags: r, rotation, label, size

I'd also like to rotate the label.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M66Ri.png)

```
fviz_cos2(pc1,choice="var")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
fviz_cos2(pc1,choice = "var")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5,angle = 90,vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried it, but error massage cams as follows:
fviz_cos2(pc1,choice = "var")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5,angle = 90,vjust = 0.5))
Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state
In addition: Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete

Comment: I didn't got this error... Try to run this:  dev.off(), and then run your plot.